# Use same background color as outlook for a windows form

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, outlook-addin

I hope you can help me with this question because I have no idea even how to look at it on internet.

I'm doing an Outlook Add-In. When you press a button, it displays a windows form I made (very similar to a Message Box but with a textbox on it). I want the color to be the same as in outlook. I noticed Outlook has 3 different set of colors (Silver, black and blue). How can I make so that my form has the same color as outlook?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/outlook-help/HV080808770.aspx) could be useful.
Furthermore you could use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx) to set the background color of your form starting from rgb value.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I kind of have the color, but now I just need a way to know which color schema is activated (Silver, Black and Blue) in order to pain mine of the same way. Any suggestions? I'm very rookie at this so please be as detailed as possible. Thanks.